# How do I perform a "hard refresh" of a view controller so that all setup is re-performed?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, cocoa-touch

This sounds terrible in practice, but I want to leverage the [Xcode Injection](http://johnholdsworth.com/injection.html) plugin/app and have a quick way to refresh the currently visible view controller to apply changes.

So for instance, if I set up certain variables in `init`, certain in `viewDidLoad`, others in `viewDidAppear`, I'd like those all to be called again. Simply manually calling `viewDidLoad` unfortunately doesn't accomplish all of this.

Any ideas?

Comment: I suppose actually dismissing and deallocating, and then re-instantiating the view controller is out of the question?

Comment: Put all your setup logic in separate methods which you call from `init`, `viewDidLoad`, etc. And then call those methods again when needed.

Comment: I suppose you could just `self.presentViewController()` back to itself.  But @Koen solution is better.

Comment: Use `viewDidLayoutSubviews` for all UI setup and You can recall it when UI changed